# Why does a monad use "return" or "unit" rather than "lift"?

Tags: design-patterns, haskell, monad

This is partly genuine curiosity, and partly a check on my understanding. I'm probably missing the point.

In Haskell, why does a monad use operations called `return` or `unit` to describe putting a type into the container -- lifting it into the monadic space? It seems more intuitive to call the operation `lift`.

Right now, in my (probably incorrect) port of monads into my own project, I'm using (pseudocode):

> MyThing.**lift**(x).bind(f)...

rather than

> MyThing.**unit**(x).bind(f)...

because it's more intuitive for me to think of lifting x into the monadic space.

Is that wrong-headed? I keep getting burned by not thinking abstractly enough, and I suspect that's the case again.

Comment: In Haskell the word `lift` is usually reserved for the idea of lifting _functions_ into the world of monads, ie `liftM :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> (m a -> m b)`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The term `unit` comes from category theory where we define a monad as two natural transformations `unit : Identity ~> m` and `join : m x m ~> m`. In case you're curious, `bind f = join . fmap f`.

`return` comes from do notation where `return` looks appropriately algol-ish. It's actually debatable whether this was a good name since it tends to suggest that `return` is some sort of control flow instead of just being a plain old function.

We usually reserve `lift` for things that are more like a functor and lift whole functions or monads. `lift :: m a -> t m a` and `liftM :: (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`.

Answer (score 10):

As Benjamin Hodgson mentioned in his comment, the term *lift* is usually applied to lifting non-monadic functions into the monad.

As for why the function is specifically called `return`, that is because it is used in the `do` syntactic sugar, which is meant to resemble an imperative C/ALGOL style code block, which typically used the `return` keyword to return a value.

Similarly, `bind` is called `SelectMany` in .NET, because *its* monad comprehensions are meant to resemble SQL queries.

Comment: George W. Noon sounds like some spaghetti western star, you should be a sheriff. Also +1 for the SQL influence on LINQ mention, it's a great anecdote that too few people are aware of.

Comment: possibly also worth mentioning that () is pronounced unit so that is also a possible place for confusion